# what is the difference between early blight of potato and late blight of potato?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

apart from different fungus causing these diseases in potato, how are Early Blight of potato and Late blight of potato different?

Answer (score 2):

Some Differences are listed here

[image]

Please consider reading these articles ([article 1](http://www.hort.uconn.edu/ipm/veg/htms/bltpot.htm), [article 2](https://extension.umass.edu/vegetable/articles/recognizing-tomato-blights))